# What does 業者など、読者本人以外による mean?

Tags: meaning

> また、**業者など、読者本人以外による**本書のデジタル化は、いかなる場合でも一切認められませんのでご注意下さい。

It's what's written in the last page of the book I was reading.

I'm not sure of what it means. Who is 読者本人? They talk about 読者係 before, is it that? Traders and so on are not allowed to digitalise that book, except for 読者. Yes?

Also, what's the kanji for よる here? 因る, 由る?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your understanding should be fine. It says basically the person who bought the book is the only one who can digitize the book.

読者本人 is literally *reader themself*, so just emphasizing *reader (in person)*.

業者 here means people who provide the service of digitizing books. It is mentioned as an example of 読者本人以外.

So, it is like *digitizing of this book by people except the reader themself, digitizing-service provider for example, is not allowed*, which I think sounds similarly confusing but semantically the meaning should be clear.

[よる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B/#jn-228572) seems to be technically 依る, but using kanji is simply uncommon.

> ３ （依る）動作の主体をだれと指し示す。「市民楽団に―・る演奏」

Comment: Can I digitalise the book? Shouldn't it be illegal?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi If you bought it and digitalize it yourself (I mean, really do it yourself not asking others to do it), it should be fine according to the sentence.